# What does bi-weekly mean?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

I was confused while looking for the meaning of *bi-weekly*. Is it twice per week or once per two weeks?

Comment: Once every two weeks.

Comment: That linked to question doesn't answer this question in any way shape or form!

Comment: Actually, *biweekly* can mean either "occurring every two weeks" and "occurring twice a week," which is why you should avoid using that word.